# How do I get my CountLines function (in Java ), to output the last number in a file?

Tags: java, io

I have the following function , which counts the lines in a simple file. This file is consisting of integers separated by newlines , but the problem is that it's going one character at a time. And so if the last line has 2 digits, it will only return the 2nd digit as the final output:

Here is my code :

```
public static int countLines(String filename) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));


    try {
        byte[] c = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        int readChars = 0;
        int lastline = 0;

       boolean empty = true;
       while (  (readChars = is.read(c))  != -1) {

         //System.out.println (" The array is + readChars " + readChars + " !!!" );

            for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i){
                Byte b  = c[i];
                int xx = b.intValue();
                lastLine =  xx; 

                if (c[i] == '\n'){
                    ++count;
                    empty = true;

                } else {

                    empty  = false;
                }      
            }   // END inner- FOR-LOOP  

       }// END WHILE-LOOP
        if (!empty) {
        count++;
       }


   int asciiVal  = lastLine;
   int lastLine2 = Character.getNumericValue(asciiVal);
   System.out.println("the last line was "  + lastLine2);

   return count;


    } finally {
        is.close();
    }

}//END method countLines
```

Here's a sample text file of the input it's reading :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
17
```

any tips appreciated. I want to learn better Java encoding, IO, etc topics related to this also. thank

Comment: What is: lastLine variable

Comment: @Abdelhak -  the last line , in the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prepared solution which is probably nearest to yours (in terms to editing distance)

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static int countLines(String filename) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));


        try {
            byte[] c = new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            int readChars = 0;
            int lastLine = 0;
            int lastNumber = 0;

            boolean empty = true;
            while (  (readChars = is.read(c))  != -1) {

                for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i){
                    Byte b  = c[i];
                    lastLine = b.intValue() - 48;

                    if (empty) {
                        lastNumber = 0;
                    }

                    if (c[i] == '\n'){
                        ++count;
                        empty = true;

                    } else {
                        lastNumber *= 10;
                        lastNumber += lastLine;
                        empty  = false;
                    }
                }   // END inner- FOR-LOOP

            }// END WHILE-LOOP
            if (!empty) {
                count++;
            }


            int asciiVal  = lastLine;
            int lastLine2 = Character.getNumericValue(asciiVal);
            System.out.println("the last line was "  + lastNumber);

            return count;


        } finally {
            is.close();
        }

    }//END method countLines

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.print(countLines("/tmp/test.txt"));
    }
}
```

What happens here:

- I'm reading as you do char by char
- Because `c[i]` is [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) byte `intValue()` return it's ASCII value. To get "real" value of this particular digit i reduce it with ASCII code of `0`. E.g., for `intValue()` of `'5'` is 53 when we substract 48 (`intValue()` of `'0'`) we get 5
- Because we use [decimal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal) to "add" new digit on the right, we need to multiply whole number by 10 and then add that digit
- When new line is detectedm lastNumber is set to 0

This solution is not best, nor bullet proof. What happen when file does not exist, or contains letters? Probably `Scanner` is better tool for this. If you wan't to learn basics I really encourage you to take a look at [CodeWars](http://www.codewars.com/?language=java)

Answer (score 2):

Using a `Scanner` as opposed to your `InputStream` to read in lines and count/print them out could be done as so.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
// All your stuff up until the while loop
while (scan.hasNext()) {
     if (sc.nextLine().equals("")) break;
     System.out.println (" The array is + scan.nextInt() " + readChars + " !!!" );
     count++;
}
```

The above would go through all lines in a text file (that contains only numbers) and prints them out and adds to count for each line passed (including the last line if there are numbers on it). Also with the above there is no need for the boolean `empty`.

`BufferedReader` uses slightly less memory than `Scanner` but `Scanner` is much easier to work with. I have no experience with `InputStream` as a method of scanning in input.

***EDIT***: Here is a `BufferedReader` example because I am bored. You will either need to add throws declarations or use a try-catch (shown) in order to use a `BufferedReader`.

```
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    // All your stuff up until the while loop
    try {
        String read = buff.readLine();
        while (read.equals("") == false && read.equals("\n") == false) {

            int nextInt = Integer.parseInt(read);
            System.out.println (" The array is + scan.nextInt() " + nextInt + " !!!" );
             count++;
            read = buff.readLine();

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

As you can see significantly more code is required for the `BufferedReader` but it is all really just preference.

Getting the last line in the file would just require minor modification. You would just keep track of each `int` as you go through them all and for each new `int` you scan in you write over the previous one and so fourth. When you run out of lines the `int` currently held in your variable would be the last one.

Comment: BufferedReader.readLine returns null on end of input, not empty string. You'd get empty string on a line that just contains a line terminator.

Comment: Just tested it and it worked, will add a check for a new line character though.

Comment: Not exactly sure why he was using that in his code, but if he needs it, it is just a copy-paste and minor adjustment. @ApproachingDarknessFish

Comment: You don't need to add a check for new line, you'd never get it from readLine. Take a look at the docs, the terminating condition is 'returning null'.

Comment: @brettf put an empty line in the middle of your test input and check what happens.

Comment: Why a down vote, but no explanation for the down vote?